# How can I start and check my MySQL log?

Tags: mysql, logging

I want to check the log in MySQL to see the queries that are being run by my application. How can I do this? I am using XAMPP and the directory to MySQL is C:\xampp\mysql.

This is what I get when I do `show variables like '%log%';`

```
mysql> show variables like '%log%';
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                              |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| back_log                        | 50                                 |
| binlog_cache_size               | 32768                              |
| binlog_format                   | STATEMENT                          |
| expire_logs_days                | 0                                  |
| general_log                     | OFF                                |
| general_log_file                | C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql.log      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  | 1                                  |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                                |
| innodb_log_buffer_size          | 8388608                            |
| innodb_log_file_size            | 5242880                            |
| innodb_log_files_in_group       | 2                                  |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir       | C:\xampp\mysql\data\               |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups      | 1                                  |
| log                             | OFF                                |
| log_bin                         | OFF                                |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF                                |
| log_bin_trust_routine_creators  | OFF                                |
| log_error                       | C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql.err      |
| log_output                      | FILE                               |
| log_queries_not_using_indexes   | OFF                                |
| log_slave_updates               | OFF                                |
| log_slow_queries                | OFF                                |
| log_warnings                    | 1                                  |
| max_binlog_cache_size           | 4294963200                         |
| max_binlog_size                 | 1073741824                         |
| max_relay_log_size              | 0                                  |
| relay_log                       |                                    |
| relay_log_index                 |                                    |
| relay_log_info_file             | relay-log.info                     |
| relay_log_purge                 | ON                                 |
| relay_log_space_limit           | 0                                  |
| slow_query_log                  | OFF                                |
| slow_query_log_file             | C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql-slow.log |
| sql_log_bin                     | ON                                 |
| sql_log_off                     | OFF                                |
| sql_log_update                  | ON                                 |
| sync_binlog                     | 0                                  |
+---------------------------------+------------------------------------+
37 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871718/how-can-i-start-and-check-my-mysql-log

Comment: Your general log file is here: `C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql.log`, error-log file is here: `C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql.err` and I think query logs are here: `C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql-slow.log`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Enable general query log by the following query in mysql command line

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Now open `C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql.log` and check query log

If it fails, open your `my.cnf` file. For windows its `my.ini` file and enable it there. Just make sure its in the `[mysqld]` section

```
[mysqld]
general_log             = 1
```

Note: In xampp `my.ini` file can be either found in `xampp\mysql` or in `c:\windows` directory

Comment: It says:

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
on

Comment: @JohnathanAu you need to be `root`(mysql `root` user) to do this.

Comment: Hey, do you mean root for the PC? How do I do that?

Comment: You need to login with username "root"

Comment: I logged in as root and did the query again and I got:

mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

I did a mysql query in PHPMyAdmin, then I opened the log and it was blank!

Comment: @JohnathanAu update your `my.ini` file then. See the update in my answer.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, I don't see the line `general_log = `. What's the default value?

Comment: @Pacerier Default value is `OFF` or `0` means disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html).

Answer (score 1):

Its given on OFFICIAL MYSQL website.

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

You can also use custom path:

```
[mysqld]
# Set Slow Query Log
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = "C:/slowquery.log"

#Set General Log
log = "C:/genquery.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the general query log is the file that you need. A good introduction to this is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, general_log didn't worked. But adding this to my.ini worked

```
[mysqld]
log-output=FILE
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = "d:/temp/developer.log"
```