# MySQL - my.ini not loading on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, configuration, load

I have installed MySQL it via wizard with the installer (5.6) and seems I'm unable to load properly the my.ini file, even though the services is targeting the correct file (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini), I'm a bit out of ideas already. Any suggestion?

After a server restart, MySQL still does have mysql_query_cache OFF and 0 as size.

I'm using mysql_cache_type=1 through the my.ini, but after server restart, the changes are not applied to mysql, my.ini looks like this at this moment:

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=40777216

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you have in your mysql.err log file ?

Comment: I can't check the error log, I did what they say here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871718/how-can-i-start-and-check-my-mysql-log to enable it but I can't, since the my.ini is not being read and I got an error trying to SET GLOBAL. I have installed mysql 5.5.36 and now I have query_type ON, however is not reading other parameters I am writting on my.ini. Any idea? I want also modify key_buff, max_allowed_packet...etc

Comment: Try `mysql --help` and part way down the output it will give a list of the ini files that it will look for.  Check if any of those exist.