# PHP page loads forever when trying UPDATE to Oracle db

Tags: php, oracle

SELECT statements function OK and very fast between my php scripts and Oracle database. But UPDATE satements take forever to run, even a small query updating one row leaves the web browser loading the page for minutes.
This is the sample code that i want to execute from localhost. but the page is loading forever...

```
The sample code is:
$connect = oci_connect("SYSTEM","admin","XE");
if($connect) {
//echo 'connected';
$qry = oci_parse($connect,"UPDATE USER SET PASSWORD='1234' WHERE USERNAME='abc'");
$res=oci_execute($qry,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
if($res){   
echo "successfully updated";
    }

}
else {
    echo 'Not connected';
}
```

Comment: $connect = oci_connect("SYSTEM","admin","XE");
if($connect) {
 //echo 'connected';
 
 $qry = oci_parse($connect,"UPDATE USER SET PASSWORD='1234' WHERE USERNAME='abc'");
 $res=oci_execute($qry,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
 if($res){ 
 echo "successfully updated";
 }
   
}
else {
 echo 'Not connected';
}

?> this is the sample code that i want to execute from localhost. but the page is loading forever...

Comment: Do you know if it's slow, or just blocked (e.g. if another session has updated the row but not yet committed, your script will wait forever)?

Comment: Thank you so much Jeffrey...:) :) I got it.. its working now...:) :)

Answer (score 0):

Two methods to debug your issue -

1. Check your query log - If the query is running as you are expecting.

   If you are using Mysql this link here can help ->
   [How can I start and check my MySQL log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871718/how-can-i-start-and-check-my-mysql-log)

   If oracle -> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12032_01/doc/epm.921/html_techref/config/querylog/qlovervw.htm
2. It could be a issue of your development environment.

   It also depends on your development environment configured properly.

   You can start from your php configuration file(php.ini).

   And do edit more details to your question.