# Unable to establish SSL connection to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ssl, mysql-workbench, remote-access, remote-server

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server over SSL, however am getting the error:

`Unable to establish SSL connection`

Steps taken:

1. In MySQL Workbench, used the SSL Wizard to certificates and keys.
2. Uploaded `ca-cert.pem`, `server-cert.pem`, and `server-key.pem` to the server.
3. In my.cnf on the server, added the following:

   `[mysqld]
   ssl-ca=/path/to/ca-cert.pem
   ssl-cert=/path/to/server-cert.pem
   ssl-key=/path/to/server-key.pem`
4. Restarted MySQL service on the server.
5. Back in MySQL Workbench, set the connection to require SSL and use the files `ca-cert.pem`, `client-cert.pem`, and `client-key.pem` stored in my local computer.
6. Tested the connection in Workbench, got the 'Unable to establish SSL connection' error.

I have also noticed that running `show global variables like 'have_%ssl';` shows that `have_ssl` is `disabled`.

Comment: Your MySQL log should have more details; on Linux it is usually at `/var/log/mysql`, on Windows [this describes how to enable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871718/how-can-i-start-and-check-my-mysql-log). Please post the relevant errors from there.

Comment: @KenY-N Unfortunately MySQL logs don't seem to be available. Checked the usual `/var/log/` path... this is a shared host

Comment: If CPanel-based hosting, [try this link](https://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=985712), or perhaps try asking over on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).